# Retrieve parameters from properties file

Tags: build, automation, hudson, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have several Jenkins parameterized jobs that uses the same parameters and parameters values.
When I have to change the default value of one of those parameters, I need to go over all of those jobs and reconfigure them.

A simple solution to this problem would be an option to retrieve all parameters from config file (in the master/ in the workspace) but I could not find a sufficient implementation for that.

**I want to be able to feed build with standard Java config file** *(in format "key"="value")* **and then refer to those parameters like every other parameters during the build.**

Do you know of an appropriate solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to read your parameters from a file as environment variables in an *Inject Environment Variables* build step. The glitch is that then you can't override them easily. One solution would be to use it in conjunction with the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin). You can then can define a boolean parameter *OVERRIDE* that would be *false* by default. You can then run your *Inject* build step conditionally only when *OVERRIDE* is *false*. When you need to override your parameters with values provided by hand (on in a custom call to run the job) specify the override values and set *OVERRIDE* to *true*.

Comment: +1: This is the way to go. I use this plugin to load my environment dependent values from config files. The config files are in SVN and the Environment Variables Build step loads these variables depending on an Build parameter. You can also inject the variables before you check your SCM. This plugin is gorgeous.

Answer (score 1):

I use hudson with ant and set parameters (customer) in my hudson job. This parameter is then the name of a property file that i open with ant as follow:

```
<loadproperties> srcFile="${project.dir}/build/resources/${customer}.properties"/>
```